# Router controlling CSS and Images

Tags: php, css

Been following along with a the PHP series and hit a snag when I try and load images and style sheets.

so it looks like the router is looking for routes for everything

```
#0 /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/index.php(7): Router->direct('css/bootstrap.c...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php on line 21
[06-Apr-2017 09:08:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/index.php(7): Router->direct('css/bootstrap.c...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php on line 21
[06-Apr-2017 09:08:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/index.php(7): Router->direct('media/logo.png')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php on line 21
[06-Apr-2017 09:08:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/index.php(7): Router->direct('js/bootstrap.mi...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Graham/Projects/OGPokedex/core/Router.php on line 21
```

As you can see it cant loads routes for any of this

this is the router class

```
<?php

class Router {
    protected $routes = [];

    public static function load($file) {
        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }

    public function define($routes){
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri){
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)){
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}
```

and my routes look like this

```
$router->define([
    '' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
    'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php',
    'search' => 'controllers/search.php'
]);
```

Any help with this would be great

Edit
My htaccess file
```

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

```

Comment: How are you trying to include the CSS file?

Comment: Just the normal way  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">

Comment: Do you have a rule in your `.htaccess` file redirecting all requests to your `index.php` file?

Comment: Same as image -- ```<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="media/logo.png"/>

        </div>
    </div>```

Comment: my htacces file ------  RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Could you add that as an edit to your post please? :)

Comment: Of course I can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140041/discussion-between-thebluefox-and-morby-raybould).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick discussion in chat, we found that the htaccess was causing the problem. The htaccess file needed to be altered to;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

As you can see, we've removed the `RewriteBase /` line.

My guess is that this line was causing the Asset URL's (`/css`, `/js`, etc) to not be recognised as files or directories by the 2 `RewriteCond` conditions. This meant these requests were redirected to `index.php`.

**Edit**

Further to my answer above, a more stable `.htaccess` setup was found;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```